# How to use variables in linux regex pattern?

Tags: linux, sed

I need to execute a sed command with pattern /^03.06.2014/ in a .sh script & command line. The date is a variable not a constant. How could i implement this? When I use a variable inside a regex pattern, the command breaks. Do I need to escape something here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
date=$(date +%m.%d.%Y)
sed -n '/^$date/,$p' filename
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes for variable expansion in sed

```
sed -n "/^$date/,\$p" filename
```

Comment: The `$p` is not a variable, it's EOF (`$`) and a command (`p`), so the `$` needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quotes to allow for shell expansion. You'll need to escape the `$` meaning EOF.

```
sed -n "/^$date/,\$p" filename
```