# How can I use a regex variable for a find and replace command in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed, replace

This is a follow-up to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64053771/) I had asked.
For that question, I received an excellent answer by @markp-fuso demonstrating the use of an array of search patters for `sed` to perform a particular substitution task.

In this question, I would like to perform the same find and replace task of replacing all forms of `pow(var,2)` with `square(var)` but I would like to do this by using a regex variable.

The sample input and output files are below:

**InputFile.txt:**

```
pow(alpha,2) + pow(beta,2)
(3*pow(betaR_red,2))
2/pow(gammaBlue,3))
-pow(epsilon_gamma,2)+5
```

**OutputFile.txt:**

```
square(alpha) + square(beta)
(3*square(betaR_red))
2/pow(gammaBlue,3))
-square(epsilon_gamma)+5
```

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23756210) and some more tinkering on https://regex101.com/r/80Hp5Z/1/, I was able to describe the text between `pow(` and `,2)` using `(?<=pow\().*?(?=,2\))`.

Using Bash, I am trying to form a two command solution where:

1. First command sets `var` to `(?<=pow\().*?(?=,2\))`
2. Second command performs `sed "s/pow(${var},2)/square(${var})/g" InputFile.txt > OutputFile.txt`

It seems once I figure out how to set `var` successfully in Step 1, I can
proceed with the command in Step 2. However, after reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229449/how-to-use-variables-in-linux-regex-pattern) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) I tried the following two commands but they did not perform any substitutions:

```
bash$ var="(?<=pow\().*?(?=,2\))"
bash$ sed "s/pow(${var},2)/square(${var})/g" InputFile.txt > OutputFile.txt
```

I would really appreciate some help forming a 2-command Bash solution as described above
that makes use of a regex variable and transforms `InputFile.txt` into
`OutputFile.txt`.

Comment: Probably a much better solution overall is to write your program in such a way that you can switch between these functions without changing the code, either via a `#define` (which obviously requires you to recompile the program, but is very easy to manage from a Makefile or similar) or even by rewriting the program so you can switch at run-time (via a command-line option then, or perhaps an environment variable).

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks, this idea is very interesting and I didn't know you can do this. If possible, could you please give me some tips or references on how I can write such a `#define` statement that allows seamless switching between `pow(var,2)` and `square(var)`?

Comment: How to replace `pow(foo(),2)` would have been a far more interesting question since matching one `)` is trivial but matching an unknown number of nested `(...)`s isn't.

Comment: Create a simple wrapper function which accepts one argument `var`, then returns either `pow(var, 2)` or `square(var)` depending on your `#define`. Post a new question if you can't figure it out (though I would guess it has been asked before; search before asking).

Comment: Ah, I see what you are trying to say. This is really cool and I can see myself using this in other situations as well. Thanks @tripleee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deal with parentheses in squared expressions, try:

**One-line Solution:**

```
perl -pe 's/pow\s*\((([^()]|\((?2)+\))+)\s*,\s*2\s*\)/square($1)/g' inputFile.txt
```

**Two-Line Solution:**

```
REGEX="pow\s*\((([^()]|\((?2)+\))+)\s*,\s*2\s*\)"
perl -pe "s/$REGEX/square(\1)/g" inputFile.txt
```

https://regex101.com/r/Dp0Duf/1.

Comment: Alexander Mashin, thanks a lot for the `perl` solution, it works perfectly. Would it be possible to make this into a two-command solution, where the first command sets `var =` a regex and then in the second command, this regex variable gets used in the `perl` command?

Comment: @procyon, create a file called, say, `t`:
`#!/bin/bash
REGEX="pow\s*\((([^()]|\((?2)+\))+)\s*,\s*2\s*\)"
perl -pe "s/$REGEX/square($1)/g" $1`
Make it executable and call it like this: `./t file`.
**P.S.** The line breaks should be before `REGEX` and `perl`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried out your bash script using `./t file`, but it converts `pow(alpha,2)` to `square(file)` instead of `square(alpha)`. Could you please tell me why this happens when it looks equivalent to your one-liner after variable expansion?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's funny. Two `$1`'s are mixed up. Try this: `#!/bin/bash
REGEX="pow\s*\((([^()]|\((?2)+\))+)\s*,\s*2\s*\)"
perl -pe "s/$REGEX/square(\1)/g" $1`

Comment: Thanks so much, Alexander Mashin. I've accepted your answer and added your updated bash script as a two-line bash solution to your answer as a suggested edit. I sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed` with one capture group:

```
s='pow(\([^)]+),2\)'
sed -E "s/$s/square\1)/g" file
```

```
square(alpha) + square(beta)
(3*square(betaR_red))
2/pow(gammaBlue,3))
-square(epsilon_gamma)+5
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rKqg3y/1)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works! I'm trying to use `(?<=pow\().*?(?=,2\))` (https://regex101.com/r/80Hp5Z/1/). Would it be possible to use that in a sed substitution command to get the same result?

Comment: No, you cannot use lookahead and lookbehind in `sed`.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. One of the things I am confused about in my question is how to first set the regex part of a `sed` command as a variable and then use it later on in the actual `sed` command. Would it be possible to add a two-liner solution to your answer where the first command sets `var` to a regex and in the second command `var` gets used by `sed` to perform the substitution?

Comment: Sorry I went to sleep after previous comment. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Your two step solution will work really well with a workflow involving 1) tinkering on regex101.com and setting a regex variable 2) applying the sed command. Thanks @anubhava, I appreciate your help!